# TensorFlow js prediction results in the same answer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have made a tensorflow js model by converting it from a python model into a tensorflow js model. The python model predicts the image and classifies it fine, however with the tensorflow js model, the predictions are always the exact same result.

```js
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      model: null,
      img: null,
      result: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testModel() {
      const example = tf.browser.fromPixels(this.img)
      const prediction = this.model.predict(example.expandDims(0))
      this.result = prediction.argMax().dataSync()[0]
    }

  },
  async mounted() {
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/model.json')
    this.img = new Image()
    this.img.src = '/test_image.png'

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you preprocessing this test image the same way you would on the Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the prediction is occurring before the image has finished loading. I think the image then would be all black pixels.